# WCF InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession & ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single still Different ThreadID in TraceLog

Tags: c#, wcf, trace

We have set our service behaviour to [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "abc", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]

as you can see we have set Concurrency Mode as Single but still we are able to see multiple ThreadID's in WCF Trace Log.

Need Help in making WCF calls Thread Safe so that each message is processed in sequenced.

Thanks,
Srujal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConcurrencyMode` controls threading **per InstanceContext**. Since you use `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession` you still allow to exist several service instances at the same time, one per session.

If you instead set `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single` you create a singleton service, i.e. only one single instance of your service. In combination with `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single` this will achieve the desired behavior:

> The service instance is single-threaded and does not accept reentrant calls. If the InstanceContextMode property is Single, and additional messages arrive while the instance services a call, these messages must wait until the service is available or until the messages time out. [(MSDN documentation ConcurrencyMode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can read more on [Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Hi nodots, thanks for your help I did tried that as well as setting the throttling attribute of max concurrent calls to 1 but still able to see different thread id's in the wcf trace logs, any idea where else to look at for the same.

Comment: With the above settings there shouldn't be different thread IDs **at the same time**. Over time however it's just a matter of how the service host handles threading: a former thread may be destroyed and a new one created.