# WCF InstanceContextMode.PerSession ConcurrencyMode.Single

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I am facing some nasty race condition which I hope I finally can explain but the WCF service setup seems to be tricky to understand for me.

We use a bunch of services with this behavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

We just refactored some code in the hope we solved a problem, but found out today it can still occur. In this race condition, we have 2 methods on one service that are called from different threads. We expect them to be "synchronous" since we define the `ConcurrencyMode` as `Single`. But based on some loggings, I am pretty sure that both methods are still running in parallel.

Is it true, that when `InstanceContextMode` is set to `PerSession`, that different threads that call this service, have "their own session", and therefore can both run in parallel?

Maybe a better question would be "when do I create a session"? Because in code we don't seem to create multiple sessions. I just create a WCF channel, which gives me back a proxy. And user code can call this proxy. Then, because we have a multi threaded application, different threads can call this WCF proxy.

If that creates "a different session" under the hoods, then that would explain one and another.

But if that's the case, what's the point in having "PerSession" at all? Because wouldn't I achieve *the exact same thing* by making the service multi threaded?

Comment: ConcurrencyMode controls threading per InstanceContext. Since you use InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession you still allow to exist several service instances at the same time, one per session. There is the same problem in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894914/wcf-instancecontextmode-instancecontextmode-persession-concurrencymode-con